# Can i connect to a local .json file on my server and template it?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a Webserver on [kasserver.com](http://kasserver.com) and with a PHP script I fetch an API every 15 mins and save it on a my webserver. Now I want to template the saved JSON data, but I can reach it local.

```
handleEvents('test, "./json/tester.json");

function handleEvents(id, link) {
    fetch(link).then(res => {
    res.json().then(
        t => {
            if (t.length > 0) {
                let output = "";
                for(let i=0, len = t.length; i < len; i++) {
                    output = data[i].person;
                }


                document.getElementById(id).innerHTML =  output;
            } else {
                document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = "<div>Aktuell sind noch keine genaueren Details verfügbar</div>";
            }
        }
    )});
}
```

But it tries to fetch a local URL instead of using the data from the Webserver. I couldn't find how to fetch a local JSON file on my server right yet.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access server's local location by client.
If your file is located in public area of PHP server, you can access it by full URL with domain

```js
function handleEvents(id, link) {
  fetch(`https://${location.hostname}${link}`)
  .then(res => {
    // ...
    // ...
  }
}
```

```js
handleEvents('test', '/json/tester.json')
```

So, you have to write the function like this.